# vector subcript out of range c++

Tags: vector, range, out

I'm trying to write a set (in mathematical sens) in C++ but I have problem. When i launch my program i have "vector subcript out of range" error. I'm using Visual Studio and its not show any error. Sorry for my bad language.

```
#include "Set.h"



template <class T>
void Set<T>::print() {
cout << endl << "{";
for(int i = 0; i < set.size() - 1; i++) {
    cout << set[i] << ", ";
}
//cout << set[set.size()] << "}" << endl;
cout << endl;
}

 template <class T>
bool Set<T>::contains(T value) {
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
    if(set[i] == value) return true;
}
return false;
}

template <class T>
void Set<T>::operator +(const T &obj) {
if(!contains(obj)) set.push_back(obj);
}

template <class T>
void Set<T>::operator -(const T &obj) {
if(contains(obj)) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    // NIE DZIAŁA
    while(i < set.size()) {
        if(set[i] == obj) break;
        i++;
    }


    while(i < (set.size() - 1)) {
        set[i] = set[i + 1];
        i++;
    }

    //set[i] = set[set.size()];
}
}

template <class T>
Set<T> Set<T>::operator +(const Set<T> &obj) {
Set<T> result;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
    result + set[i];
}

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < obj.set.size(); i++) {
    if(!result.contains(obj.set[i])) {
        result + obj.set[i];
    }
}

return result;
}

template <class T>
Set<T> Set<T>::operator -(const Set<T> &obj) {
Set<T> result;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < set.size() - 1; i++) {
    if(!contains(obj.set[i])) {
        result + set[i];
    }
}

return result;
  }

 template <class T>
 Set<T> Set<T>::operator *(const Set<T> &obj) {
Set<T> result;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < set.size() - 1; i++) {
    if(contains(obj.set[i])) {
        result + set[i];
    }
}

return result;
 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The message means you're trying to access a vector element that doesn't exist.  You should use the debugger to find out where.

Comment: Also I noted that you are a bit inconsistent in your loops, e.g. I see for loops with `i < set.size() - 1` and `i < set.size()` as well as while-loops which seem to do more or less the same thing. In `operator *` shouldn't you be assigning the result of `result + set[i]`?

Anyway, on-topic: where and when are you getting the error? I.e. in which method of the `Set` class and what does the calling code look like?

Comment: When i'm trying to substract two sets or product two sets.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem. It did in print method. It's correct version of this method:

```
template <class T>
void Set<T>::print() {
if(!set.empty()) {
    cout << endl << "{";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < set.size() - 1; i++) {
        cout << set[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << set[set.size() - 1] << "}" << endl;
    cout << endl; }
}
```

Thanks for help!